# Custom leftBarButtonItem issue in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationitem

I have problem on custom left bar button item in ios 7 and above. Here i can move the button frame (x pos = -10). But could not change left bar button x pos.

Here my code:

```
BackButton *backButton = [[BackButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44) viewFrom:self];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

In iOS 7.1: [image]

In iOS 6.1 [image]

Kindly anyone help me to archive this. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Solution is make a UIButton and add to a navigationBar subViews.
Example:

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0,0,60,44)];
backButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:backButton];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 44.0f)];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(-20, 0.0f, 60.0f, 44.0f);
[backView addSubview:backButton];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```